# OpenAPI Specification - Use of Discriminator and oneOf - Spectral listing

Tags: openapi, discriminator, spectral

#### OpenAPI Discriminator using oneOf

A minimal example of using a discriminator with an openApi spec and linting with Spectral.

#### Error message:

```
~/git/openapi_discriminator/openapi/v1/api.yaml
 22:23  error  oas3-valid-media-example  "example" property must match exactly one schema in oneOf  paths./discriminatortest.get.responses[200].content.application/json.example
```

#### Background

OpenAPI schema with simple GET method which can return different types of `Animal`.

A subclass of `Animal` is defined which can either be a `Chicken` or a `Dog`.

The only property `Animals` have are `legs`.
A discriminator is used to distinguish between a `Chicken` or `Dog` where a `Chicken` has `two` `legs` and a `Dog` has `four` legs.

#### Aim

I was to verify that the example in a request response matches only one schema.

#### Question

I thought using a discriminator might mean that anything with `two` `legs` is a `Chicken` and anything with `four` `legs` is a `Dog`.

Am I mistaken and it is still legitimate for a `Dog` to have `two` `legs`, and this is why it's erroring?

I could change it to `anyOf` but then the discriminator has no use?

#### Code

Code repo - [openapi_discriminator](https://github.com/MCR2019/openapi_discriminator.git)

`openapi_discriminator/openapi/v1/api.yaml`:

```
openapi: "3.0.3"
info:
  title: Open API Discriminator Example
  version: "v1"

tags:
  - name: discriminator

paths:
  /discriminatortest:
    get:
      tags:
        - discriminator
      summary: Example using discriminator
      description: "Demonstrate a minimal example"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Created
          content:
            application/json:
              schema: {$ref: "schemas.yaml#/components/schemas/Animal"}
              example:
                legs: "two"
```

`openapi_discriminator/openapi/v1/schemas.yaml`:

```
openapi: "3.0.3"

components:
  schemas:

    Animal:
      type: object
      discriminator:
        propertyName: legs
        mapping:
          two: Chicken
          four: Dog
      oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Chicken'

    Chicken:
      type: object
      required:
        - legs
      properties:
        legs:
          type: string

    Dog:
      type: object
      required:
        - legs
      properties:
        legs:
          type: string
```

`openapi_discriminator/openapi/.spectral.yml`

```
extends: spectral:oas
rules:
  info-contact: false
  info-description: false
  oas3-api-servers: false
  openapi-tags: true
  operation-tags: true
  operation-operationId: false
  operation-description: true
```

Run linting command: `spectral lint "openapi/v1/api.yaml" --ruleset openapi/.spectral.yml`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, considering you asked this so long ago. The problem here is that you haven't explicitly declared the available values for legs. You know and I know that a dog has four legs and a chicken has two legs, but the schema doesn't.
Put another way, the discriminator has to discriminate based only on the value of the `propertyName`, so that is what the example has to match.

Adding in the `enum` values will fix your problem:

```
openapi: "3.0.3"

components:
  schemas:

    Animal:
      type: object
      discriminator:
        propertyName: legs
        mapping:
          two: Chicken
          four: Dog
      oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Chicken'

    Chicken:
      type: object
      required:
        - legs
      properties:
        legs:
          type: string
          enum:
            - two

    Dog:
      type: object
      required:
        - legs
      properties:
        legs:
          type: string
          enum:
            - four
```

Also, the `mapping` is probably not so useful for you right now:

```
          two: Chicken
          four: Dog
```

Depending on your use case, e.g. if you're generating documentation from the schema, this will mean your generated docs show two options ("two" and "four"). So perhaps you might consider making it:

```
          chicken: Chicken
          dog: Dog
```